# Unable to deploy my Vue app on github pages

Tags: vue.js, github, vuejs2, github-pages

I followed the doc for deploying my vue app on gh-pages but running into an error. Here is my deploy.sh as mentioned on the official doc https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#github-pages:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# abort on errors
set -e

# build
npm run build

# navigate into the build output directory
cd dist

# if you are deploying to a custom domain
# echo 'www.example.com' > CNAME

git init
git add -A
git commit -m 'deploy'

# if you are deploying to https://<USERNAME>.github.io
# git push -f git@github.com:<USERNAME>/<USERNAME>.github.io.git master

# if you are deploying to https://<USERNAME>.github.io/<REPO>
git push -f git@github.com:VishalGulati/vue-grid-poc.git master:gh-pages

cd -
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

PS - I ran the deploy.sh on my branch `gh-pages`. My app is buit using vue-cli 4.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: This is an issue with Git, not vue, https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: First of all, your repository should have a public setting instead of private. Second, it seems, you have problems wit access to your repository through ssh -> ```git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).```

Comment: @ValeriiVoronkov - the repo has public access.

Comment: ssh access woks fine?